# How to add custom options in magento through code with unique option id?

Tags: magento, product

I want to add custom options with unique id to product. I already added few custom option to product using this code, its working fine

```
 $options_print[$sku] = array(
                    'title' => 'Select Size',
                    'type' => 'drop_down',
                    'is_require' => 0,
                    'sort_order' => 0,
                    'values' => array()
                );
                $options_print[$sku]['values'][] = array(
                    'title' => '5',
                    'price' => 0.00,
                    'price_type' => 'fixed',
                    'sku' => '',
                    'sort_order' => '1'
                );
                $options_print[$sku]['values'][] = array(
                    'title' => '6',
                    'price' => 0.00,
                    'price_type' => 'fixed',
                    'sku' => '',
                    'sort_order' => '1'
                );
```

My problem is, I want to assign unique id to drop-down option 'Select size' so i can retrieve it using that id whenever I need it through code but it seems there is no option to assign 'sku' or 'option_id' to it.

Magento is automatically assigning option id to it such as,

```
Array
(
    [label] => Select Size
    [value] => 10
    [print_value] => 10
    **[option_id] => 267**
    [option_type] => drop_down
    [option_value] => 729
    [custom_view] => 
)
```

I have no control over it, option id keep changing with each product, so its difficult for me to retrieve this option value based on its id.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

```
$productSku = $_product->getSku();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$productId = $product->getIdBySku( $productSku );

$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productId);

$attVal = $product->getOptions();

$optStr = "";

// loop through the options
foreach($attVal as $optionKey => $optionVal) {

    //$optStr .= "<br/>";

    //$optStr .= $optionVal->getTitle().": ";

    $optStr .= "<select style='display:block; clear:both;' name='options[".$optionVal->getId()."]'>";

    foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal) {
        $optStr .= "<option value='".$valuesVal->getId()."'>".$valuesVal->getTitle()."</option>";
    }

    $optStr .= "</select>";

}

echo($optStr );
```